# searching in List<>

Tags: c#-4.0, bindingsource

i want to find value in List<> but i am not getting the integer value. Here is my code from that i want to find the value in the List

```
private void txtnapsaserach_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       //decimal find = decimal.Parse(txtnapsaserach.Text);

       if (decimal.Parse(txtnapsaserach.Text) > 0)
       {
       List<NapsaTable> _napsatabs = this.napsaTableBindingSource.List as List<NapsaTable>;
       this.napsaTableBindingSource.DataSource = 
        _napsatabs.Where(p =>p.NapsaRate.Equals(txtnapsaserach.Text)).ToList();

       }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
    }
}
```

any solution for me . Because this works for me when i try to find string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void txtnapsaserach_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     float value;
     if (!float.TryParse(txtnapsaserach.Text, out value))
         return; // return if text cannot be parsed as float number

     if (value > 0)
     {
        var napsatabs = napsaTableBindingSource.List as List<NapsaTable>;
        napsaTableBindingSource.DataSource = 
            napsatabs.Where(p =>p.NapsaRate == value).ToList();
     }
}
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

> i want to find value in List<> but i am not getting the integer value.

Your `p.NapsaRate` is either integer type or floating point number, **(probably decimal)**  Convert your `txtnapsaserach.Text` to decimal value and then compare it in where clause.

```
decimal rate = 0;
if(!decimal.TryParse(txtnapsaserach.Text), out rate)
{
//Invalid number in textbox
}

this.napsaTableBindingSource.DataSource = 
        _napsatabs.Where(p =>p.NapsaRate == rate)).ToList();
```

if `p.NapsaRate` is of type double or float you can parse them accordingly using `Double.TryParse` or `Double.Parse` etc

The **reason you are not getting any error** is that you are using `object.Equals` method for comparing decimal value with string. You should always use `==` for equality comparison of value types.